# What happened to my post?

Tags: support, status-norepro

I've written up what I think is a good challenge, gotten feedback in the sandbox, and then posted it to the site.  Upon submitting I'm met with a page that shows:

[image]

When I simply try to resubmit my post, I get a message saying there is a duplicate which links to the above page!  For reference, here is the [post in question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/76395/wargame-tank-simulation).

What happened? Is there anything I did which may not play nice with the site?  How can I post my code challenge?

Comment: SE is currently experiencing issues. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277523

Comment: This is something that's happening network-wide at the moment, try to post your question in a little while.

Comment: Try again now. It seems to have been fixed.  Edit: [it worked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76395/wargame-tank-simulation).

Comment: It's happening again! I clicked on the link to the question and the oops screen popped up.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That's because the "link" is to an error page and not to any post.

Answer (score 3):

## This was all SE's fault, obsolete now.